# What's best result for normal form theory of non-autonomous dynamical system

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

Given an autonomous dynamical system, we could find its rest points and then try to understand the grems of the vector field on the neighborhoods of the rest points. In particular, there is the famous Poincare-Dulac theorem.

My question is:

Is there a parallel theory established for non-autonomous systems? What are the best result known?